# How do I fix inconsitent brightness with HDR turned on?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, brightness

I have this weird issue with my monitor. I have the HDR turned on. And while adjusting my screen, if I changed the color/brightness slider in monitor settings or nvidia settings in ubuntu, it gives me the perfect display. But If I restart then dark colors are fine but, bright colors are not that well. Like if I visit any website with background I don't see borders and sometimes text as well. It again gets fixed by moving the slider a little bit in any direction. Sometimes just opening the nvidia color settings seems to fix this.

I don't know what is going on and how to fix this. I don't have this issue on windows.